# Change ship to in WooCommerce order list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-admin

Is it possible to change the "Ship to" column from the WooCommerce order list? I'd like to change this column to show the billing address instead (because I don't use shipping addresses). I could change the store a shipping address (based on the billing address) - but it seems like unnecessary, duplicated data to store in the database.

[image: WooCommerce Shipping Address]

Comment: you mean you want to show the billing address instead on this?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Comment: check answers please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the `Ship to` column with `Billing address`

**Step 1 :** Go to wp-admin -> WooCommerce -> Orders

**Step 2 :** Click on **Screen Options** in above right corner.

**Step 3 :** Uncheck `Ship to` Checkbox and check the `Billing` Checkbox

**Step 4 :** Click Apply Button to save change

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! I've never noticed the Screen Options tab before!

Answer (score 0):

Hey the  above answer is right please check image below:-

[image]

The options available into woocommerce->order top right corner screen options